# Java IO. loading from .txt file as a variable

Tags: java, save, java-io

I am making a simple program where I can keep track of my savings. I have included week no., income, and saved fields. I save this data to a text file and then can retrieve it to a text area. How can I keep track of my running total, "total", when closing the program then running it again. I have used an array as a running total, but this starts over when I kill it then reopen it (obviously).

here is my code for the save and read. to sum up I want to be able to retrieve the last field "total" as a variable so it can be added onto the new input.

```
    //get week and validate:
    strWeek = txtWeek.getText();
    if (strWeek.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Week Number");
        return;
    }
    else
        week = Integer.parseInt(strWeek);

    //get income and validate:
    strIncome = txtIncome.getText();
    if (strIncome.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Income");
        return;
    }
    else
        income = Double.parseDouble(strIncome);

    //get saved:
    strSaved = txtSaved.getText();
    if (strSaved.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Saved");
        return;
    }
    else
        saved = Double.parseDouble(strSaved);

    total = total + saved;

    txtOutput.append(week + "\t" + income + "\t" + saved + "\t" + total + "\n");
    txtWeek.setText(null);
    txtIncome.setText(null);
    txtSaved.setText(null);

    try
    {
        File output = new File("C:\\savingsApp/Savings.txt");
        BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(output.getPath(), true));
        outFile.write(week + "\t" + income + "\t" + saved + "\t" + total);
        outFile.newLine();
        outFile.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Savings updated"); 
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IO file error");
    }
```

---

```
 txtOutput.setText(null);
    //Declare:
    String incomingString = "";
    int counter = 0;
    //get file:
    try
    {
        File inputFile = new File ("C:\\savingsApp/savings.txt");
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(inputFile));
        incomingString = inFile.readLine();
        while (incomingString != null)
        {
            counter++;
            txtOutput.append(incomingString + "\n");
            incomingString = inFile.readLine();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error loading file");
    }
```

Comment: and is not working because...?

Comment: -fGo. saving and retrieving is working. getting that last field "total" to be set as a variable when I load it, ready to add to the new total when I save does not. don't know how I go about doing it

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Make `runningTotal` an `ArrayList` and save to a separate file before killing your program. This could be in comma (or tab) separated form. For instance `runningTotal.csv` could look like this:

> 150,200,50,...,300

When you read in `savings.txt` you can also read in `runningTotal.csv` and then add any more totals to the end of the `ArrayList`. When you close the program again, update `runningTotal.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you are really asking is a way to parse the text you are getting from the file. The, a way to achieve this could be by using *java.util.Scanner* for example as shown in here:

```
private Map<String, String> parseData(String text) {
  Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
  data.put("week", scanner.next());
  data.put("income", scanner.next());
  data.put("saved", scanner.next());
  data.put("total", scanner.next());
  return data;
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
...
while (incomingString != null) {
  counter++;
  String totalStr = parseData(incomingString).get("total");
  txtOutput.append(incomingString + "\n");
  incomingString = inFile.readLine();
}
```